# Encrypt a message with multiple interpretations

Tags: algorithm, encryption

I'm researching to see if there is an algorithm the encrypts different things with different keys to product the same output.

So let's say I have 2 messages.

```
var message1 = "My password is: Doggies!1"
var message2 =  "My password is shdhe93-4"
```

And two keys.

```
var key1 = "DummyKey"
var key2 = "RealKey"
```

I would like to be able to encryption it like so

```
var encryptedText = encrypt([message1, message2],[key1,key2]
```

And decrypt it like so

```
decrypt(encryptedText, key1) === message1
decrypt(encryptedText, key2) === message2
```

Is there a standardized way to achieve this?

Comment: For what purpose? A duress situation, where someone is forcing you to give them your key? If so, it'd somehow have to understand that "My password is" and "Doggies!1" need completely different handling, so no.

Comment: See also: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/193315/is-there-a-term-for-encryption-where-decrypting-with-the-wrong-key-will-still-re

Comment: Not what your asking for, but you might want to investigate [steganography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steganography), which is hiding messages in other data, and can be used to hide mulitple messages in one place.  Used with a key to locate the message (so call "steganogrphic encryption"), you can hide both a real and a "false" message and "leak" the false message key to confuse an adversary.

Comment: For a symmetric algorithm like AES-128, that seems like a tricky problem that may not have a computationally feasible solution. For something like RSA it's probably not that hard to find different RSA keys that decrypt a given ciphertext to two different prearranged plaintexts. Similar problems are the stuff of RSA capture-the-flag challenges that you might find on e.g. cryptohack.org.

Comment: @ceejayoz, yes the different handling would also ensue but that's not the scope of this question.  I don't see why it wouldn't be possible the message can be any size the decryption message would only cypher the contents it needs, and all the source messages can be compressed in a way would would help minimize the size

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk yeah I'll would accept any way that works, I don't care about how it's encypted mostly I'd just prefer the fact that the same blob can be interpreted differently and I would also prefer that the total number of decryptable message not be discernable 100%

Comment: "**Deniable encryption** makes it impossible to prove the existence of the plaintext message without the proper decryption key. This may be done by allowing an encrypted message to be decrypted to different sensible plaintexts, depending on the key used."

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to *choose* the different plaintext messages that the keys produce, then you generally require the key to be about as long as the message.  The standard technique with a key as long as the message is the [one-time pad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad), and in fact it is very easy to make a one-time pad key that decrypts any ciphertext to whatever plaintext you want.

I know that's not really want you want -- keys that long are not convenient -- but that's how it is if you want to choose the plaintexts.

If you only need different keys to produce *plausible* plaintexts, though, then these days you can make a scheme that actually works pretty well, using a LLM:

1. Prompt an LLM with a prompt like "write a 100 word secret text file that I might find on someone's computer."  (try this on bing chat or chat GPT -- it's fun!)
2. Use a high temperature to make the output "imaginative" and variable.  The LLM will require a sequence of random numbers to determine word to produce at every position.
3. Determine the sequence of numbers that produces the message that you really want, and encrypt it with your key to make the ciphertext.

Now, to decrypt your message you just decrypt the random numbers and feed them to the LLM after giving it the same prompt, and it will product your real message.  If you use any *wrong* key, though, the LLM will get a completely different sequence of random numbers, and will produce a completely different, but still "plausible" result.

Comment: I don't care about the key length, or the cypher text length.  the only thing I care about is that 1.  There is no indication of how many messages are stored in the cypher,  2.  The cypher text output is the same.   The method encryption method will have access to all keys and messages at the time of encryption as well.

Comment: The idea of using an LLM, as a cyper text is interesting, provided I can obtain enough entrophy.